# Angular 4 - using component selector in external HTML

Tags: angular

I have problem with binding component selector with external html.

I have TwigComponent :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'twig-component',
  templateUrl : 'twig.component.html'
})
export class TwigComponent implements OnInit {
  htmlFromBackend: TwigResponse;

  @ViewChild('alertContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container;
  componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private http : HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getHtmlFromBackend();
    this.createComponent('success');
  }

  createComponent(type) {
    if(this.container != null) {
      this.container.clear();
    }

    const factory: ComponentFactory<AlertComponent> = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(AlertComponent);

    this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);

    this.componentRef.instance.type = type;

    this.componentRef.instance.output.subscribe(event => console.log('event ' + event));
    console.log('innerHTML =' + this.componentRef.instance['innerHTML']);
  }

  getHtmlFromBackend() {
    this.http.get<TwigResponse>('http://localhost:8080/api/html/content?page=dwa')
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.htmlFromBackend = data;
      });
  }
}
```

And twig.component.html

```
<div [innerHTML] = "htmlFromBackend?.html"></div>
```

And Alert Component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-alert-component',
  template: `
    <h1 (click)="output.next('output')">Alert {{type}}</h1>
  `,
})
export class AlertComponent {
  @Input() type = 'success';
  @Output() output = new EventEmitter();
}
```

And html from backend :

```
<ng-template #alertContainer></ng-template>
```

And there is my question. 
What is a proper way to bind component selector with HTML passed from an external source?

I also tried pass html as selector  but none of them work.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question when trying to solve it for myself.

In case you were still looking for an answer, I wrote a [blog post](https://www.arka.com/blog/dynamically-generate-angular-components-from-external-html) about it.